# Data oriented collision detection

Tags: c++, cpu, data-oriented-design

I'm trying to make collision detection from a data oriented perspective. I want to remove the enemy once a collision has been detected,not sure how to make it as optimal as possible for the CPU, right now I do like this:

```
bool EnemyManager::isCollidedWithBullet(float x, float y, int& numEnemies){
    for(auto it = positions.begin(); it != positions.end(); ++it){

        // Collision detected
        if(x > it->first && x < it->first+enemyWidth && y < it->second + enemyHeight){
            positions.erase(it);
            numEnemies = positions.size();
            return true;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Is it fine to remove the integerpair right away from the vector like I currently do, or should I somehow store all the "detected" collisions in another vector and proceed from there? I'm new to think in data-oriened terms and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How many comparisons does your program perform to evaluate collision detection in a frame? It sounds like you're doing `O(n^2)` comparisons (on the assumption that `isCollidedWithBullet` is called for every entity active in the world) - if so, that's inefficient.

Comment: I am calling this function **once** every frame as long as the bullet is active (I only have one bullet at a time). All the positions of all the enemies are stored in the vector positions of type pair.

Comment: Then what exactly do you mean by storing all the “detected” collisions since there is only one of them (as you `return` after detecting it)? You have an O(n) linear search here and O(n) deletion so it isn't making things any worse. You could try using something like kd-tree for better performance, though, if you have lots of “enemies”.